# Using App.Config to derive which class/variables to use

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, interface, app-config

I'm building a selenium framework which needs to behave differently between different customers e.g. 2 customers will have slightly different webpages

I'm trying to drive this from the app.config appsettings e.g.

```
<add key="Customer" value="ABC" />
```

I then have a Customer classes:

```
public static class Customer
    {
        public static string CustomerName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Customer"];
        public static string custAddress = {CustomerName}.custAddress ; //this is obviously wrong - how do i do this?...
    }

public static class ABC
    {
        custAddress = "customer abc address";

    }

public static class DEF
    {
        custAddress = "customer def address";

    }
```

I want to then call it the simplest way possible to get the value e.g.

```
var address = Customer.custAddress;
```

...which will be set depending on the app.config setting.

I'm a c# newbie so apologies for the lack of clarity - i've been trying to figure out how to cast the customer string into the class of its namesake. I thought interfaces may also be an option but struggling with the complexity. Is there a better way?

Comment: Sounds like you want dependency injection bundled with some sort of strategy or factory pattern. Maybe it is also reasonable to think about making the behavior customizable independently from specific customers? Otherwise you'll end up with endless special-implementations for specific customers which all need to be tested etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you have a set of settings per customer and the address is simply `AppSettings["Address"]`.

This way you don't need to modify your code when a 3rd customer is added. If you keep `class ABC` then there is not much point in having settings.

Comment: Thanks - could you explain a little more please? How can i differentiate between the address for 2 different customers - i'm guessing that means i would have multiple AppSettings["Address"] in my app.config, one for each customer.

Comment: You would have two config files.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance - i 've implemented the solution below and it works well which is about the level of my skils atm.Many thanks.   https://mitasoft.wordpress.com/2011/09/28/multipleappconfig/